# How to create translucent window frame in java

Tags: java

frame containing background image also, and should be traslucent

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Translucent and Shaped Window](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/) support in Java. This is still (as of Java 6) not in the public API, so as such it is subject to change. This link has [some more examples](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=260).

Comment: +1 Excellent links. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163544/re-paint-problem-on-translucent-frame-panel-component/2166500#2166500