# Transparent JFrame background

Tags: java, transparency, jframe, background-image

Is it possible to make a JFrame that has a transparent background and draw an image on it, so only the image will be visible with no border or background?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [Translucent and Shaped Swing Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) by Kirill Grouchnikov.

Comment: Link is now dead. Google suggests this blog post: http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2008/02/27/translucent-and-shaped-windows-in-core-java.html

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it's possible in many ways. This is one of them:

```
setUndecorated(true);
setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.5f));
```

4th float (which I set to 0.5f) in Color's constructor is alpha channel. It can be 0.0f - 1.0f depend on transparency you want.

Comment: This is worked for me once I replaced `0.5f` with `0.0f`. Nice Answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should make content pane transparent too.

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
frame.setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

If your JFrame is a local variable or field:

```
myJFrame.setUndecorated(true);
```

If your class extends JFrame:

```
setUndecorated(true);
```

Comment: true that since jdk7, transparency is only supported for undecorated frames. How to call methods should be basic knowledge, though :-)

Answer (score 0):

For a Mac OS X example, see [*Re-paint problem on translucent frame/panel/component*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163544/re-paint-problem-on-translucent-frame-panel-component/2166500#2166500).

Answer (score 0):

setOpacity(0.50f);//50% opaque