# How to make JFrame transparent?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparent

How to make JFrame transparent? I want to make my JFrame transparent. User should see the background when my JFrame is on top of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent JFrame background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533650/transparent-jframe-background)

Comment: An easy tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zecGJfNHPWo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do not have any objection in using restricted API classes then you can do this with `AWTUtilities` class and `setWindowOpacity()` method of that class. [Here](http://harryjoy.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/make-jframe-transparent/) and [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/03/18/translucent-and-shaped-swing-windows.html) is a tutorial on how to use it? And [here](http://harryjoy.wordpress.com/2012/08/25/transparent-jframe-using-jna/) is the version using Java native access.

**code example**

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            javax.swing.JFrame fr = new NewJFrame();
            com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(fr, 0.7 f);
            fr.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: public static void main(String args[]) { 
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                javax.swing.JFrame fr = new NewJFrame();
                com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(fr,0.7f);
                fr.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: I didn't want to do that since it is just meant to enhance your answer... Do not know how to format the code in a comment.

Comment: Ok. Click on help link while commenting it shows formatting help.

Comment: Suppose you didnt want to use restricted API's, is there another way to do this?

Comment: @user489041: Then you might have to dive in JNI.

Comment: nice blog post :-) Though you might consider to add a reference to the original article at java.net as there as well.

Comment: @user489041 it's part of jdk7 - so updating might be an option

Comment: @kleopatra: I will update post to have reference to java.net as soon as possible. Java 7 is still not used much so most of people avoid it for now.

Comment: I must note, that since using this, I was only able to get it to work on Windows. It seems it is not available in Linux. This was using java 1.6.20. Might be different with java 7. Haven't used it yet.

Comment: The setWindowOpacity is not suitable for mac, I can't down vote the answer as I don't have enough points yet but martini's answer is much better.

Answer (score 15):

I found another solution.

Set the background color of your frame to

```
// Set the frame background color to a transparent color
yourFrameHere.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

And remember to set the opacity off of the contentpane (your JPanel or other component)

```
// turn off opacity of the content pane
yourContentPaneHere.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: I don't see the `setOpaque()` method.

Comment: It is a method of the abstract class JComponent. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque(boolean)
So, every JPanel and other components have this method.

Comment: When I try to do this, I get a ```java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException``` with the message ```The frame is displayable```. How do I fix that? I tried to call ```setBackground()``` before any other calls such as ```pack()``` but it didn't help.