# exception: "Can not access restricted api" java

Tags: java, api, exception

I am trying to make my frame transparent using `AWTUtilities` class as suggested on my previous question: [How to make JFrame transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660908/how-to-make-jframe-transparent). But getting exception as `Can not access restricted API`.  How can I solve that?

Comment: If you are looking for an alternative to make frame transparent try [JNI Wrapper WinPack](http://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper/winpack).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its IDE like eclipse throwing this error. You can look at http://java.globinch.com/tag/restricted-api/**strong text** to see how to get around it.

If you can find an alternative to use of sun API, its better as this is subject to change

Comment: this is for eclipse but i'm using netbeans.