# How can i design a professional looking JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jframe

I want to design my GUI app's Top-level window to be a professional looking, to give you an example of what i am talking about, check the image attached with this post [Sample GUI design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383332/create-a-transparent-jframe-in-java-swing)

If there is a tutorial available that will be great

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you think that looks professional and why what you are normally making is not?

Comment: If you can define "professional looking", then maybe someone can answer...

Comment: I don't want the plain looking jframe like this http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/7677/plainjframe.png, a tutorial on how to design a frame similar to the one i gave in the question will be nice

Comment: good code equals good GUI and excelent code sometimes excelent GUI, without Custom Look&Feel or Translucency, everything is about used LayoutManagers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to write a custom Look-And-Feel.

- See for example http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/sce/index.html
- [Custom Java Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3954646/714968) for more examples

If that looks like too much work, the there are various colour and icon settings that can be tweaked - see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) and the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html).