# repaint() leaves trace of object initial position

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I'm implementing a JFrame program that is supposed to mimic balls bouncing with wall & between other balls in a concurrent setting. While the balls are correctly displayed and updated, it leaves the trace of the very first position. Seems like it's the edge plus some gradient gray color.
[Current look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAKrV.jpg)

I've followed steps here [Transparent JFrame background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533650/transparent-jframe-background) to set background as transparent

Frame instantiation:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bouncing Ball");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setContentPane(new BouncingBall(640, 480));
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }
```

JPanel repaint:

```
    class PaintCanvas extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
            super.paintComponent(graphics);
            // wall.drawWall(graphics);
            for (int i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
                Ball ball = balls.get(i);
                ball.drawBall(graphics);
            }  
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }
    }
```

Ball drawing:

```
    public void drawBall(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(new Color(1, 1, 0, 1f));
        graphics.fillOval((int)(posX - radius), (int)(posY - radius), radius * 2, radius * 2);
    }
```

I could not find any simlar posts on Stack Overflow or anywhere... Any idea greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please give us [MCVE]. We can not know how you manage balls...

Comment: So, after a little bit of experimentation, I was able to, basically, get it to work.  First DO NOT PAINT ANYTHING when the component is first constructed or added to its parent container.  Instead, create a `start` method which initialises the `balls` and starts your main loop.  AFTER the main window is displayed (ie `setVisible(true)` is called), add another `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` call which calls the `start` method - what you're trying to do is delay the initial rendering of the component until after the window is visible.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing how and when `balls` is initialized.  Is it ever null when paintComponent is called?  Is it initialized in a thread other than the event dispatch thread?