# PC Toast Message with Java

Tags: java, windows, toast

I have a Java Desktop Application which runs in the background and has a System Tray icon. When I want to tell the user something or when they interact with the icon I want to use "Toast" which is the only name I know for it. Toast is a box without a frame that pops up on the bottom right of the screen. Google Talk has exactly what I am talking about (I think Google started it). I tried searching for some example code but all I found was Toast for the Android.

So, how can I make Toast with Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent to Android's Toast or Mac OSX Growl in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668790/equivalent-to-androids-toast-or-mac-osx-growl-in-java-swing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying [Twinkle?](http://www.swingfx.ch/) It looks very similar to the Google Talk/Chrome desktop notifications.

It has it's own API and the source code is free to view (license needed for commercial though).

Comment: The twinkle link is broken.