# Java monospace draw string

Tags: java, swing, fonts, truetype, lcd

How can I draw a String in Java (using Graphics2d) in monospace mode? I have a font that looks like LCD screen font, and I want to draw something like LCD label.

I am using [Digital 7 Mono](http://www.dailyfreefonts.com/fonts/info/4774-Digital-7-Mono.html) font.

Do you know where I can find another font that will be monospace and lcd (I wan to type only digitals)?

Comment: Welcome to SO, javaAmator!  Unfortunately, even though you're doing a project in Java, this question isn't really suitable for SO because the act of finding a font isn't programming-related.  I suggest you ask over at http://www.doctype.com/ where there are more design-oriented folks.  If you ever have questions about stuff like algorithms, programming language syntax or bugs in code, though, we'll be happy to help!

Comment: @Lord Torgamus: I agree with your comment, but I proposed an answer to the drawing question. Sorry if I preempted your offer to help. I usually stick with the platform-specified font families, so I'd welcome any additions or corrections on how to select alternate fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I draw a String in Java (using Graphics2d) in monospace mode?

The essential method needed to render text is [`drawString()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29), as outlined below. There is no "monospace mode", *per se*, but even proportionally spaced fonts typically use a constant width for digit glyphs .

```
private static final Font font = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 32);
private static final String s = "12:34";
...
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setFont(font);
    int xx = this.getWidth();
    int yy = this.getHeight();
    int w2 = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(s) / 2;
    int h2 = g.getFontMetrics().getDescent();
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.drawString(s, xx / 2 - w2, yy / 2 + h2);
}
```

There's a complete example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163544/re-paint-problem-on-translucent-frame-panel-component/2166500#2166500), and you can extend a suitable `JComponent` to control positioning using a layout manager, as seen [here](http://sites.google.com/site/trashgod/celltest).