# Java: Transparent Windows with non-transparent components?

Tags: java, swing, opacity

I just met the utilities (`com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities`) to make your JFrame **really**  transparent. Documentation [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/). This works very good. Even in Linux with the desktop effects with wobbly windows turned on. But I want to make also a non-transparent component on the transparent JFrame.

Does anyone know, if this is possible, how?

Here is the code I used:

```
import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;

/* "this" is the JFrame */
this.setUndecorated(true);
AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, true);
AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(this, 0.5f);
AWTUtilities.setWindowShape(this, new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0f, 0f, (float) getWidth(), (float) getHeight(), 15f, 15f));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, [*Translucent Windows*](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/) applies to the entire `java.awt.Window` and contents, but you might try the approach shown below and in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166500).

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setBackground(new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.1f));
f.setUndecorated(true);
f.add(new JLabel("<html>Testing<br>1, 2, 3</html>"));
f.pack();
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Linux... On mac, this is the solution for my problem... Sad...

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: Well, neither does the `AWTUtilities` demo: "Note that the effects may not be supported by the underlying platform..."

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is `setWindowOpaque` to `false` and draw the background with low alpha (or 0 alpha if you want complete transparency). The components will still be drawn opaque. See [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/#Enabling-Per-Pixel-Translucency) and look at *per-pixel translucency*.