# Drawing non-transparent content on transparent window

Tags: java, swing, graphics, transparency

So I'm trying to draw a solid red oval on a transparent window. I later want to do something more complex with multiple shapes, so using setWindowShape isn't what I'm looking for. This is the code I'm using so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaDock extends JFrame{

    public JavaDock(){
        super("This is a test");

        setSize(400, 150);

        setUndecorated(true);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         JPanel panel = new JPanel()  
         {  
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  
            {  
               Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
               g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
               g.setColor(Color.red);  

               //Draw an oval in the panel  
               g.fillOval(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);  
            }  
         }; 

        panel.setOpaque(false);
        setGlassPane(panel);  
        getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
        com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(this, 0.5f);
        setVisible(true);
    }

     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        }

     public static void main(String[] args){
         JavaDock jd = new JavaDock();
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. I see the red oval. I don't have access to AWTUtilities so maybe that is the differenece.

Comment: Indeed it is. the window is suppose to be transparent, but the oval needs to be non-transparent.

Comment: +1: I asked it too. And still searching for a good solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372016/java-transparent-windows-with-non-transparent-components

Answer (score 4):

You are applying a global transparency to you window, so naturally everything in it will be at least as transparent as the global value. You probably want per-pixel translucency. Replace

```
com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(this, 0.5f);
```

with

```
com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false);
```

This leaves just your oval visible and it will be completely opaque. More infos can be found [in this Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/)

Comment: changing that gave me this:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The effects for decorated windows are not supported.

Comment: Odd, what platform and JRE-version are you using? I pasted your code and just changed the line (Sun JDK 1.6.0_18 on WinXP).

Answer (score 0):

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create(); 
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear); 
g.setColor(Color.red);   
g.fillOval(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
```

Code doesn't look quite right. I would try:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g; 
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear); 
g2d.setColor(Color.red);   
g2d.fillOval(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
```

or just use:

```
g.setColor(Color.red);   
g.fillOval(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
```

Comment: None of those worked, and oddly enough using g and not g.create() made the oval go from black to red.