# Java Custom JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I want to draw a custom version of a JFrame. Is is possible to extend to a JFrame and draw over it?

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find a solution. Can someone help point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "draw over it"? You can draw on its layers without extending it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`setUndecorated(false)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29) to disable the host platform's window decorations, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166500).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this site from Sun (Oracle...):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

This describes the layers of JFrame which you will have to override.

You can modify the drawing of the panes down below and make the background transparent. Then override the `paint` method on the Content Pane (or Glass Pane) and draw the frame as you wish.