# How do I create a custom floating Swing component without a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, uicomponents, custom-component

I'd like to create a custom swing component such as a desktop widget which does not require a JFrame (or to extend it) to be printed on the screen.

I don't want to extend the JFrame because my component is really simple and JFrame implements a lot of functionality I dont need.

Who do I start? Which class should I extend?

Many Thanks

EDIT ---------------------------------------

Thanks guys!

I'll check the references you sent.
Also, is it possible to java to draw on the screen without swing API?

Comment: What functionality don't you need? You can invoke [`setUndecorated(true)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29) on your `JFrame`, but regardless, you'll need a container object to render your components with!

Comment: Toolbars, menubar, child components, dragging ...

Comment: @Mikhas, Then it sounds like invoking the method on your `JFrame` will do the job, although I don't understand the "child components" part...Anyway, if you wanted to add more customization to your frame, consider reading [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows)

Comment: Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163544/re-paint-problem-on-translucent-frame-panel-component/2166500#2166500).

Comment: @trashgod, +1, good ole Java2D...very cool!:)

Comment: +1 on trashgod comment :) for referencing my answer.  I love this screenshot: http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/9195/capturadepantalla201002.png

Comment: JWindow, if you don't want the button in the taskbar.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want the functions a `JFrame` provides and just want floating graphics then use a  `JWindow`.  It does not have window decorations.

Example with plain label in a JWindow:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JWindow w = new JWindow();
    w.add(new JLabel("Testing a Window!!!!!"));
    w.setLocation(300, 300);
    w.pack();
    w.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Um, I think you need a [top-level container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html).

Comment: @Trashgod, I assume you could have an invisible Frame as the owner for the Window. I haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: @trashgod, you got me curious so I just tried and added an example.  The Window does need an owner, but that owner does not need to be visible.

Comment: @jzd why AWT Containers, is there something specific

Comment: @mKorbel, the question was how to avoid a JFrame.  And want to extend/use instead that has less functionality.  It is a strange question, but a Window fits the requirements.

Comment: @jzd for this question is only JDialog answer, how can I foud out I can't see difference between Awt Frame and Swing JFrame, looks like as this topic is nonsence... :-) +1

Comment: The topic is a little bit nonsence.  However, in my example I create a Frame, but just use it as an owner.  The Window is the only thing that is set to visible.

Comment: @mKorbel, looking back at this with a fresh view, I have no idea why I just didn't use a JWindow instead.  I have updated my example.  Thanks

Comment: @mKorbel, yea, I just wanted you to know that thinking about it with a clear head made me reconsider your comment about AWT vs Swing.

Answer (score 1):

All in all, you'll need to familiarize yourself with [Java2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/index.html), as demonstrated by *@trashgod*'s comment. In particular, [Composting Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/index.html). And understand that using a top-level container to render Swing components is always required.

**NOTE**

If *@trashgod* provides an answer, I'll gladly remove mine and up-vote his accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Depend on what you need. Probably an undecorated JFrame is all you need. I don't really understand your argument about "all the functionality I don't need", because, at different levels  you'll get it anyway, either by another component or by the underlaying OS. You can't get rid of that.

Now addressing your question you can always use a `JDialog`

Comment: JFrame leave a button in the taskbar (uncool); (J)Window is usually the one of choice (imo)

Comment: Yeap,  much better than a (J)Window is a `JDialog` wich doesn't leave the button in the taskbar either and still toplevel containter

Comment: JDialog w/o parent Frame uses a shared swing frame (which can be obtained via `new JDialog().getParent()` )

Comment: It is still not clear what does the OP means with *a lot of functionality I dont need*