# Circle enemy detection in TD game

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java tower defense game, but I've got a problem: I cant make the tower find enemies within a circle. My code:

```
if(twrsq.intersects(GameScreen.enemies[i])) {
    shooting = true;
    shotEnemy = i;
}
this.twrsq = new Rectangle(
    x - (twrsqsize/2), y - (twrsqsize/2),
    width + twrsqsize, height +  twrsqsize);
```

`twrsq` holds the current rectangle; this needs to be a circle. `GameScreen.enemies[i]` holds a rectangle too. I'm trying to make a circle from `twrsq` and make them intersect with the enemy.

How can I accomplish this?

Edit:  I got it kinda working; I got now this [screenshot](http://screenshotuploader.com/s/01/2a383Cl1x):

```
if(cir.intersects(GameScreen.enemies[i])) {
    shooting = true; shotEnemy = i;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `java.awt.Rectangle` and `java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D` implement the `Shape` interface. The latter's `contains()` method may be useful.

Comment: Can you explain further please?

Comment: There's an example using `Rectangle` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6810665/230513); there's an example using `Ellipse2D` [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/scaledview).

Comment: I'm working with shape now how can i draw an outline of them like the borders?

Comment: `Graphics#draw()` for the outline; `Graphics#fill()` for the interior.

Comment: ok ty :) another question:
  
I got it kinda working i got now this:screenshotuploader.com/s/01/2a383Cl1x if(cir.intersects(GameScreen.enemies[i])) shooting = true; shotEnemy = i; }