# JavaFX: multiple snapshots in single image

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I learned to use `snapshot` to make an `Image` object out of a node. Having multiple `Group`s that hold various strokes, I'm now trying to create a single Image with strokes from both groups. For this purpose I'm using the following code:

```
Group strokes1;
Group strokes2;
WriteableImage im = null;

SnapshotParameters params = new SnapshotParameters();
params.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
params.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(0, 0, 400, 400)); 

im = strokes1.snapshot(params, im);
im = strokes2.snapshot(params, im);
```

The documentation for the `snapshot` function says that

> "If the image is non-null, the node will be rendered into the existing image."

However, the resulting Image `im` only contains strokes from `strokes2`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: doing some more tests it seems that the `fill` parameter from the `SnapshotParameters` is ignored when an image is passed into the `snapshot` function - is that possible?

Comment: Can you post a runnable example of what you are trying to do ?

Comment: There's really not much more code that is relevant to this, to be honest. So there are some `EventHandler<MouseEvent>` that create `Path` objects that are inserted either into `strokes1` or `strokes2`(depending on certain conditions). Both `strokes1` and `strokes2` are added to a `Pane` with `drawingPane.getChildren().add(strokes1)` and `drawingPane.getChildren().add(strokes2)`.

Comment: Thing is, if I comment out ´im = strokes1.snapshot(params, im);´, I see the what comes from the line below it, and vice-versa. So the single lines work correctly, but if I try to combine both snapshots it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve your goal is to use [setComposite()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setComposite%28java.awt.Composite%29) method on the [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) of the [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) to be converted, this solution is discussed briefly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823631/java-opaque-color/7824225#7824225) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148453/layer-multiple-bufferedimages-on-top-of-one-another).

this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tarrsalah/5608005) provide a runnable complete example of the approach.

[image: App snapshot]

[image: Image snapshot]