# How to set transparent png to JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am making java desktop application using swing. I want to set png to jbutton. but i can't set transparent image. I want to do as in android like set background null so transparent image can be set.

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE,

Answer (score 9):

Try this :

```
button.setOpaque(false);
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
button.setBorderPainted(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

try `button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("path/to/image.png"))))`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this example program, is this what you asking for ?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonTransparentImage
{
    private BufferedImage originalImage, modifiedImage;
    private ImageIcon image;

    private JButton imageButton;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Transparent Image on JButton");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        getModifiedImage();
        image = new ImageIcon(modifiedImage);
        imageButton = new JButton(image);
        imageButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN.darker());

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(imageButton);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void getModifiedImage()
    {
        try
        {
            originalImage = ImageIO.read(
                new URL("http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/" + 
                    "gaganisonline/images/swing/stackoverflow/geek3.gif"));
            modifiedImage = new BufferedImage(
                originalImage.getWidth(),
                originalImage.getHeight(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);       
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to read the Content of the Image.");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        Graphics2D g2 = modifiedImage.createGraphics();
        AlphaComposite newComposite = 
            AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f);
        g2.setComposite(newComposite);      
        g2.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new ButtonTransparentImage().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

[image: TRANSPARENT IMAGE]

Simply change this line `image = new ImageIcon(modifiedImage);` to `image = new ImageIcon(originalImage);` to see the difference :-)

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/); sadly, the UI delegate, e.g. `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel` may overrule you.

Comment: Aha, just learning how to paint in Swing, so cann't question your judgement as always :-) . So any wonderful example for a workaround to this scenario ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a good, cross-platform approach; Java 7 tries to remedy that. Instead of using `setBackground()`, compose the image in `g2` using a translucent background, similar to how it's done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2166500/230513) with `CLEAR`.

Answer (score 2):

**ImageIcon cup = new ImageIcon("images/cup.png");
    JButton button2 = new JButton(cup);**

This will help you lot. for more information you can click on this link

[Jbutton Tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JButton.html)

[Jbutton Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html)

Answer (score 1):

To create a `JButton` with a transparent PNG, I use :

```
JButton jButton1 = new JButton(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("yourImage.png")
```

To create a `JButton` with a **scaled** transparent PNG, I use :

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("yourImage.png") 
JButton jButton1 = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getScaledImage(icon.getImage(), 32, 32)));


/**
 * Resizes an image using a Graphics2D object backed by a BufferedImage.
 * @param srcImg - source image to scale
 * @param w - desired width
 * @param h - desired height
 * @return - the new resized image
 */
private Image getScaledImage(Image srcImg, int w, int h){
    BufferedImage resizedImg = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
    Graphics2D g2 = resizedImg.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g2.dispose();
    return resizedImg;
}
```

Then if you don't want visible border use :

```
jButton1.setOpaque(false);
jButton1.setBorderPainted(false);
jButton1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

Comment: If you do not want the focus border to be displayed, also add jButton1.setFocusPainted(false)