# jbutton RGBA glitch

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jbutton, rgba

I am using RGBA for the coloring. I want the button transparent, but to be able to set the degree of transparency, hence the alpha. Now it looks fine until I do anything that calls a repaint/paint like hover or focus. If I set opaque to false, it does make it transparent, I just don't want this 100% transparent. It is not the image I paint in the background either. It does not have a problem with RGB, just RGBA.

these don't work:

```
jButton1.setContentAreaFilled(true or false);
jButton1.setOpaque(true or false);
```

Here is my jButton color code:

```
jButton1.setBackground(new Color(255,0,0,100));
```

Here is what it looks like.[image: jbutton glitch]

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help sooner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem looks something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163544/re-paint-on-translucent-frame-panel-component). The answers there may help you get the translucency right, but you'll need to do it in a custom `ButtonUI`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751311/creating-a-custom-button-in-java-with-jbutton/5755124#5755124).

Before: [image: before]

After: [image: after]

`ButtonUI`: [image: buttonui]