# AlphaComposite.CLEAR not working

Tags: java, awt, alpha-transparency

I have two JPanels on a JLayeredpane. One of them displays a pdf and the overlapping one has a transparent background (I have used setOpaque(false)).
Now I can add drawings to the transparent panel such that it seems I'm actually annotating the pdf. I want to have a eraser tool to erase these annotations. I tried using the following code

```
@Override
public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
    g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR));
    g2.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
    g2.draw(path);
}
```

where path is the shape constituted from a number of lines. Now instead of drawing a **transparent line** over the earlier drawings **a black line is being drawn**. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that an instance of `AlphaComposite.CLEAR`, equivalent to `AlphaComposite.Clear`, is a composite mode that clears both the color and the alpha of the destination. "Neither the source nor the destination is used as input." In effect, you can't *draw* with `CLEAR`. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2166500/230513) illustrates a common usage. To get the effect you want, keep a copy of the unaltered image and `draw()` an eraser-sized sub-image over the destination `BufferedImage` as the mouse moves.

Comment: hey could you please help me out with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450110/graphics2d-scale-not-working-when-zooming-out-images-on-centered-jpanel) question?