# Draw transparent path

Tags: java, swing, draw

I'm developing a java application for draw through the drag of the mouse. 
I need the `JPanel` to be transparent, but in this way lose the function rubber. 
With the `getBackground()` can set the transparent color to use, but the path is not going to erase what was previously drawn.

Comment: Also consider the approach suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17414933/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Drawing with transparent means... drawing with transparent, so the previous color stays intact. What you want is clearing a part of the image (you're drawing on an image surface, right?). That can be done using the clearing rule of [AlphaComposite](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html).

```
// Assuming Graphics2D g, maybe from BufferedImage
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
// drawing now clears
```