# How can I effectively find a Graphics2D rendering error?

Tags: java, swing, debugging, netbeans, graphics2d

Can you suggest a method of identifying the source of a rendering error from a debugger?

Misko Hevery [classifies](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/17/unified-theory-of-bugs/) bugs into three categories:

- Logical
- Wiring
- Rendering

Its clear to me that my problem is a rendering bug.

I have a Swing application with a Panel that contains multiple layers.  Rendering all the layers can take a significant amount of time so the application uses a thread pool to render layers and tiles from layers into BufferedImages.   When it comes time for the Event Dispatch Thread to render the panel the most-recently rendered BufferedImages are drawn to the screen.

This setup has performed adequately.

A new feature requires that a certain layer type support transparency.  Something, somewhere isn't preserving the transparency. The error could be in a number of places, possibly in the implementation of the objects to be rendered, the error could possibly be in the offline rendering thread implementation.  Its possible that the many BufferedImages aren't combined together correctly in the EDT rendering code.

I'm not asking anyone to look at the code and tell me where the error is.

What I want to know is what techniques people have found particularly effective in troubleshooting a Graphics2D rendering issue.

I'm a big supporter of unit tests but I'd prefer to start with another technique.

Is there a method or trick to visually inspect a BufferedImage or Graphics2D object from the debugger?

In the Netbeans Variables and Watches windows[image: Example Watch window] Netbeans sometimes uses PropertyEditors to display variable values.  In this example image the value of foregroundColor and backgroundColor are shown as small swatches of the Color's value.

Is there an easy way to add/enable a Netbeans PropertyEditor which would display the contents of a BufferedImage?

I could temporarily sprinkle the code with method calls to write the various BufferedImages encountered to the disk such that they could then be inspected offline.  It might work but it would be tediious to match the file on disk to the source code.

What would you do?

Comment: What type are you specifying to the `BufferedImage`?

Comment: There's no easy way to achieve this, I would start by reducing the number of layers been rendered and allow each one to be inspected.  I might write some out to disk and I might even consider having a look at [`DebugGraphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DebugGraphics.html), [for example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/DebugGraphics.htm)

Comment: @MadProgrammer There are many BufferedImages involved but they are all created like this `BufferedImage mBufferedImage = new BufferedImage((int) d.getWidth(), (int) d.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might compare your approach to the one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2166500/230513) with regard to clearing the buffer:

```
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
```

In the worst case, you can break at a point in which your `image` is accessible and set a watch on the expression `image.getRGB(0,0)` with the display set to hexadecimal. The high order byte is the `alpha` value: `FF` is opaque, and `00..FE` represents varying transparency.

Comment: Your first suggestion - Which I interpret as "look for code that deviates from a known to work pattern" is a good suggestion.  The problem is that there is quite a bit of tricky code to inspect.

Comment: I believe your second suggestion is essentailly  "Don't inspect the entire image. Watch the transparency of a single known pixel."  I think for my situation this is the better suggestion.

Comment: Right; you'll need to infer which corner to examine based on the image(s); when you catch the bad frame, you'll likely find an attempt to clear using an opaque color and/or the wrong mode.